# how to overwrite the search box?

Tags: 7, forms, search

```
<div class="fr_search">        
  <form action="/"  accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" id="search-theme-form">
    <input  name="search_theme_form" id="edit-search-theme-form-1" size="15" value="" class="form-text" />
    <!-- … -->
  </form>
 </div>
```

The above code is generated by the Drupal Search module. I want to add this code to the form.

```
<select class="search_l" onchange="selectSearch(select)">
  <option value="0">whole site search</option>
  <option value="1">google search</option>
</select>
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would rather implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to alter the form returned by [search_box()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_box/6). If mymodule.module is the name of your module, then you should add the function `mymodule_form_search_box_alter(&$form, &$form_state)`. You need also to replace the form submission handler with your own.

```
function mymodule_form_search_box_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit']['#weight'] = 10;

  $form['search_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios', 
    '#options' => array(t('Whole site search'), t('Google search')),
    '#default_value' => 1,
    '#weight' => 5,
  );

  // Replace the search.module handler with your own.
  if (in_array('search_box_form_submit', $form['#submit'])) {
    $key = array_search('search_box_form_submit', $form['#submit']);
    unset($form['#submit'][$key]);
  }
  array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_search_box_submit');
}
```

You could also show the form field containing the text to search inline with the radios you add.
The code I reported replaces the form submission handler with `mymodule_search_box_submit()` that must be implemented from your own module. This is the code executed from the submission handler implemented by search.module; I report it as reference.

```
function search_box_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // The search form relies on control of the redirect destination for its
  // functionality, so we override any static destination set in the request,
  // for example by drupal_access_denied() or drupal_not_found()
  // (see http://drupal.org/node/292565).
  if (isset($_REQUEST['destination'])) {
    unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
  }
  if (isset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination'])) {
    unset($_REQUEST['edit']['destination']);
  }

  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'search/node/' . trim($form_state['values'][$form_id]);
}
```

As reference, I report here the code of the search.module function that builds the search box form.

```
function search_box(&$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form[$form_id] = array(
    '#title' => t('Search this site'), 
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#size' => 15, 
    '#default_value' => '', 
    '#attributes' => array('title' => t('Enter the terms you wish to search for.')),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'search_box_form_submit';

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: which file should i put the function search_box(){} in. i can't understand the code under Replace the search.module handler with your own.well, could you give me an explaination .thank you

Comment: `search_box()` is the function that builds the form, and it is defined in search.module; it doesn't need to be replaced. The code that replaces the form submission handler is doing exactly that: it replaces the submission handler defined from the Search module with `mymodule_search_box_submit()` (change the function name with the name of the function defined from your module). What you need to do is to create your own module that implements `hook_form_search_box_alter()` and the submission handler.

Comment: If the name of your module is, e.g., custom_module then you need to replace `mymodule_` in the code I reported with `custom_module_`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this, IMO, would be to simply use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are better off using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) than editing the template (no offense, but that is really bad practice).

You probably want to add a new form element and a submit handler to the search form, so you can handle the submit action and process the value of the new element.

Comment: beat me to it by a couple seconds :)

Comment: I agree!! Will delete my answer to not keep bad solutions around, not sure why theme override came to my mind first.

Answer (score 1):

There is a search-block-form.tpl.php template:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-block-form.tpl.php/7

In that template it's important to have hidden fields. Mine currently looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="search_form">
      <?php print $search['hidden']; ?>
        <input type="text" name="search_block_form" class="input" />
        <input type="submit"  id="edit-submit--3" name="op" value="" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is great for just the search box but the results displays on the main search page, which I need to override. For that reason I want to be able to use the search-result(s).tpl.php and block files. But I can't seem to get the code correct in my template file. I tried using the code on this page changing obviously the theme template but the changes I made to the tpl.php shows they are not being used. What am I doing wrong?

```
function dove_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) {
  $variables['search_results'] = '';
  if (!empty($variables['module'])) {
    $variables['module'] = check_plain($variables['module']);
  }
  $index = 0;
  foreach ($variables['results'] as $result) {
    $variables['search_results'] .= theme('search_result',
      array(
        'result' => $result,
        'module' => $variables['module'],
        'extra_classes' => $index % 2 === 0 ? ' even' : ' odd',
      )
    );
    ++$index;
  }
  $variables['pager'] = theme('pager', array('tags' => NULL));
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_results__' . $variables['module'];
}
```

I just thought I'd add the reason I need to edit the files is I'm using custom search module which is great but in the result it's giving me the type:allthecontenttypes in the input form plus the search results. U G L Y.